# Enable multiple menu items to be selected concurrently

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I want to be able to select multiple items at once as shown in the following picture:

[image]

With the following code, I am only able to select one item at a time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/nav_group1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item1"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Item 1" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item2"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Item 2" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_item3"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Item 3" />

    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/nav_group2"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item4"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Item 4" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item5"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Item 5" />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item6"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:title="Item 6" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

In the Java code, I manually check the selected menu item, but the previously checked items always become unchecked. How can I prevent this?

```
mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if person selects any of the menu item in a group and if it happens hide/disable the click events of other menu items in that particular group.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        menu.findItem(R.id.option2).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.option4).setVisible(true);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```